# Select Case FROM Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, union

In a purpose of reporting and creating report (MS SQL SERVER 2014) which will compare number of transactions and amounts from last day, same day last week and same day last month I need some query like this one, which is not working:

```
Select 
   Acquirer = case when Date = @Day then a.Acquirer
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Acquirer
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Acquirer
              end
,  RC =       case when Date = @Day then a.RC
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.RC
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.RC
              end
, Desc =      case when Date = @Day then a.Desc
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Desc
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Desc
              end
, Day_Tr_Count =  case when Date = @Day then a.Count end
, LWD_Tr_Count =  case when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Count end
, LMD_Tr_Count =  case when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Count end
, Day_Tr_Amount =  case when Date = @Day then a.Amount end
, LWD_Tr_Amount =  case when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Amount end
, LMD_Tr_Amount =  case when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Amount end

from
  ( select * from T1
     union
    select * from T2
     union
    select * from T3) x
group by Acquirer,RC,Desc
```

All 3 tables have pretty same structure:

```
T1,T2,T3(acquirer,RC,Desc,Count,Amount,Date).
```

Report should be:

```
result_table(Acquirer,RC,Desc,Daily_Count,Last_Week_Day_Count,Last_Month_Count,Daily_Amount,Last_Week_Day_Amount,Last_Month_Day_Amount)
```

Comment: Step 1: You probably want `UNION ALL`.

Comment: How is it *not working*?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: because he does not have a, b, c tables in the query aliases

Comment: I never understand why people write huge queries with so many basic errors... They should do it step by step in case they don't know what they're doing.

Comment: I perfectly know what I am doing, I tried to type entire query, also, maybe missed something like aliases but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You have an aggregation query with no `group by`.  Perhaps:

```
Select v.Acquirer, v.RC, v.Desc,
       Day_Tr_Count =  sum(case when Date = @Day then a.Count end),
       LWD_Tr_Count =  sum(case when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Count end),
       LMD_Tr_Count =  sum(case when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Count end),
       Day_Tr_Amount =  sum(case when Date = @Day then a.Amount end
       LWD_Tr_Amount =  sum(case when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Amount end),
       LMD_Tr_Amount =  sum(case when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Amount end)

from (select * from T1
      union all
      select * from T2
      union all
      select * from T3
     ) x cross apply
     (values (case when Date = @Day then a.Acquirer
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Acquirer
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Acquirer
              end,
              case when Date = @Day then a.RC
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.RC
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.RC
              end,
              case when Date = @Day then a.Desc
                   when Date = @LastWeekDay then b.Desc
                   when Date = @LastMonthDay then c.Desc
              end
             ) v (Acquirer, RC, Desc)
group by v.Acquirer, v.RC, v.Desc;
```

Note:  `desc` is a bad name for a column (or anything else).  It is a SQL keyword (think `order by`).